# Closed under extensions without zero object

Tags: category-theory

Suppose A is an abelian category and $\mathcal{B}$ is a full subcategory of A. If $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under extensions, must it be closed under isomorphisms? We require that $\mathcal{B}$ contains the zero objects of A no? If $A \rightarrow B$ is an iso then $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0$ is an extension so if A is in $\mathcal{B}$ then so is B. What is such subcategory does not contain zero objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody referred to a full subcategory of an abelian category closed under extensions, then I'd assume that they probably meant the subcategory to be additive, and therefore containing a zero object.

But you could, for example, take $\mathcal{A}$ to be the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field, and $\mathcal{B}$ to be the full subcategory containing all vector spaces of dimension at least $2$, and one vector space of dimension $1$. Then technically $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under extensions but not under isomorphisms.